# Select counts of occurrences

Tags: sql, select, hive

I have a table with dates and some text - I'm looking for counts of specific strings within them. For example:

```
myDate, Text
2016-06-27, Cat food
2016-06-27, Dog toy
2016-06-27, Dog food
```

Something like

```
select myDate, sum(if text rlike 'Dog', 1, 0) dog_count
             , sum(if text rlike 'Cat', 1, 0) cat_count
from blah
```

will return 2 rows:

```
myDate, dog_count, cat_count
2016-06-27, 2, 0
2016-06-27, 0, 1
```

Is there a way to select both dog_count and cat_count in the same row, thusly?

```
myDate, dog_count, cat_count
2016-06-27, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query is missing a `group by`. Just add it to get the result on one row for a given date.

```
select myDate
, sum(if text rlike 'Dog', 1, 0) dog_count
, sum(if text rlike 'Cat', 1, 0) cat_count
from blah
group by myDate
```

Comment: Thanks vkp - I had the group by myDate in place but I had a group by text as well. I had modified an existing query to build this and forgot to update the group by clauses.